# Spark, wasb and Jetty 11

Tags: azure, hadoop, pyspark, jetty

When running Pyspark 3.1.1 with zulu11.45.27-ca-jdk11.0.10-win_x64 and trying to access Azure wasbs://container@store.blob.core.windows.net
using [hadoop-azure-3.2.2.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-azure/3.2.2/hadoop-azure-3.2.2.jar) [jetty-util-11.0.1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/11.0.1/jetty-util-11.0.1.jar) [jetty-util-ajax-11.0.1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util-ajax/11.0.1/jetty-util-ajax-11.0.1.jar)

I get the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.csv.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Properties org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getProperties()'
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.createPermissionJsonSerializer(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.<clinit>(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.createDefaultStore(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1368)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you get the answer to the above problem?

Comment: Nope, no solution so far. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log` class was deprecated on [Jetty 10+](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.x/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Log.java).

I was able to solve this issue by using the latest version from 9.4.45, like:

```
jetty-util-9.4.45.v20220203.jar
jetty-util-ajax-9.4.45.v20220203.jar
jetty-server-9.4.45.v20220203.jar
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: So it always worked with version 9. but the challenge is to upgrade it to version 11+ Thx